# How to pass system date in sendkeys in Selenium Webdriver (not hardcoded)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
WatchFromDate().sendKeys("2018-07-03");

// public WebElement WatchFromDate()
{

    return driver.findElement(fromDate);
}

By fromDate= By.id("from");
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please take a look at this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

the steps to send the system date in selenium could obtain the date with a specific format and then send this variable. Something like that:

```
public void WatchFromDate(){    
  DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");
  LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
  driver.findElement(fromDate).sendKeys(dtf.format(localDate));
}
```

1. The `dtf` variable defines the format for the date (i.e. 2018/07/13)
2. The `localDate` variable obtain the current date, but this date has too much precision.
3. The `dtf.format(localDate)` sentence adjust the current date obtained in the localDate, to the defined format in `dtf` variable.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.